# //SOLVED Facing issue while fetching email id from Mongodb and passing it to nodemailer for automatic email sending

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

//Finally able to solve this. I am able to fetch the email from Mongodb and send email to that specific email ID.

I am trying to create a project out of interest and got stuck with the below issue. Please extend your support.

Problem statement : Fetch email id from Mongodb and pass it to the nodemailer for automatic email trigger.

***File contents :***

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const empschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    FIRSTNAME :{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    LASTNAME :{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    EMAILADDRESS : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    EMPID : {
        type: Number,
        required : true,
        unique: true
    },
    DEPARTMENT : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    DOB : {
        type : Date
        
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("EmployeeData", empschema)
```

**Route :**

```
//GET employee data by Birthday from MongodB
router.get("/getBirthday", getBirthday)

//POST Birthday Email to the employee
router.post("/sendEmail/:id", sendEmail)
```

**Controller**

```
   //GET EMPLOYEE BY BIRTHDAY
async function getBirthday(req,res,next){
  
  try {
    const employees = await EmployeeData.aggregate([
      { 
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
                
              { $eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: '$DOB' }, { $dayOfMonth: new Date() }] },
              { $eq: [{ $month: '$DOB' }, { $month: new Date() }] },
            ],
          },
        }
      }
    ]).exec(function(error, items){
      if(error){return next(error);}
      res.send(items)
    })
    
  }
    
  catch(err){
    throw err;
   }
 
  }




//SEND BIRTHDAY EMAIL
  async function sendEmail(req, res)  {
    const id = req.params.id
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
  
    sendEmailFunction(name, email)
      .then((result) => res.json(result))
      .catch((error) => res.json(error.message));
  };


  //sendEmailFunction FOR EMAIL SENDING
  async function sendEmailFunction(name, email) {
    const CLIENT_EMAIL = process.env.MAIL_USERNAME;
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID;
    const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI;
    const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN;
    const OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      CLIENT_ID,
      CLIENT_SECRET,
      REDIRECT_URI,
    );
  
    OAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
    try {
      // Generate the accessToken on the fly
      const accessToken = await OAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
  
     // Create the email envelope (transport)
      const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          type: 'OAuth2',
          user: CLIENT_EMAIL,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
          refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
          accessToken: accessToken,
        },
      });
  
      // Create the email options and body 
   
      const mailOptions = {
        from: `<${CLIENT_EMAIL}>`,
        to: email,
        subject: `Sending email from code`,
        html: `${name} Enjoy learning!`,
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: 'happyBirthday.png',
            //path: path.join(__dirname, `e-books-path/${name}.pdf`),
            //contentType: 'application/pdf',
          },
        ],
      };
  
      // Set up the email options and delivering it
      const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
      return result;
  
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

**Birthday.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import BirthdayList from './BirthdayList';
import client from './axioscalls/api';
import {useAuthContext} from '../hooks/useAuthContext';  

function Birthday() {
    
    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
    
    const {user} = useAuthContext();
  

    function getUsers() {
        client.get('/api/employee/getBirthday', {
           headers : {
               'Authorization' : `Bearer ${user.token}`
           }
        })
           .then((response) => {
                   setEmployees(response.data);
              });   
        }

        useEffect(() => {

            if(user){
                getUsers();
            }
       
        },[]); 
    

    const handleBirthdayEmail = (id)  => {
        if(!user){
            return 
        }
            try{
                
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'warning',
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send it!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
                })
                
                .then(result => {
                    if (result.value) {
                        const [employee] = employees.filter(employee => employee._id === id)
                
                        const birthdayEmployee = {
                    
                            name : employee.FIRSTNAME,
                            email : employee.EMAILADDRESS,
                            }
                            console.log(employee.EMAILADDRESS)
                            client.post(`/api/employee/sendEmail/${id}`, birthdayEmployee, {
                                headers : {
                                            'Authorization' : `Bearer ${user.token}`
                                         }
                                    })
                                    .then((response) => {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            icon: 'success',
                                            title: 'Sent!',
                                            text: `${employee.FIRSTNAME} ${employee.LASTNAME}'s birthday greetings has been sent.`,
                                            showConfirmButton: true,
                                            //timer: 1500,
                                        });
                                      });
     
                    }})    
                }
        catch(err) {
            console.log("Unable to send the birthday message to the employee" +err.response)
        }  

}


     

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {/* BirthdayList */}
            {(
                <>
                    <BirthdayList
                      employees={employees}
                       handleBirthdayEmail={handleBirthdayEmail}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Birthday;
```

**BirthdayList.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function BirthdayList({ employees, handleBirthdayEmail}) {

 return (
        <div className='contain-table'>
            <table className='striped-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SERIAL NUMBER</th>
                        <th>MONGODBID</th>
                        <th>FIRSTNAME</th>
                        <th>LASTNAME</th>
                        <th>EMAILADDRESS</th>
                        <th>EMPID</th>
                        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th colSpan={3} className="text-center">
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {employees.length > 0 ? (
                        employees.map((employee, i) => (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>{i+1}</td>
                                <td>{employee._id}</td>
                                <td>{employee.FIRSTNAME}</td>
                                <td>{employee.LASTNAME}</td>
                                <td>{employee.EMAILADDRESS}</td>
                                <td>{employee.EMPID}</td>
                                <td>{employee.DEPARTMENT} </td>
                                <td>{employee.DOB} </td>
                                <td className="text-left">
                                    <button
                                        onClick={() => handleBirthdayEmail(employee._id)}
                                        className="button muted-button"
                                    >
                                        Send Birthday message
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan={10}>No Employees</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BirthdayList
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You call `fetchEmployeeData()` twice and hence execute `app.listen(8080)` twice. This leads to the observed error. Also, the function `fetchEmployeeData` returns nothing, yet you try to access the member `fetchEmployeeData().employeemail`. What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Then why do you need an `app` at all? Are you writing a web service? Consider simplifying your task and trigger the whole process by invoking the function `fetchEmployeeData()` directly in the Node.js console. Think about the web service later.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I actually want to access the employeemail and employee name which i get from mongodb, inside mailer.js and use the employeeemail specifically in nodemailer mailoptions 'to' parameter.

Comment: You are actually right. I might have complicated it unnecessarily. let me try and get back to you. Thankyou for your quick responses.

Comment: I tried this new approach but i am still stuck with how should i access the return value of the promise into the nodemailer mailoptions 'to' parameter. Can someone guide me please. 

I have updated the original post with code.

Comment: I am finally able to do this now. Successfully able to send email to user fetching the email from MongoDb. Updated code in the original post for anybody's reference.